# Sans que without subjunctive?

Tags: grammaire

Why does the sentence

> Elles sont venues sans que je les ai invitées

not use the subjunctive?  I thought "sans que" always requires the subjunctive, so what is the exception in this case?

Comment: What makes you think this sentence is correct? It should be spelled “sans que je les **aie**”, which is a subjunctive. Native speakers may plausibly make this spelling error, it's pronounced the same.

Answer (score 4):

**Sans que** like **avant que** requires the subjunctive. So the correct form is

> Elles sont venues sans que je les aie invitées.

**sans que** conveys here a negative concession. See here: http://mamiehiou.over-blog.com/article-sans-que-indicatif-subjonctif-ou-conditionnel-quel-mode-choisir-79956674.html.

Comment: Shouldn't it be "Elles sont venues sans que je _ne_ les aie invitées"

Comment: @vc Le ne explétif n'est pas nécessaire : https://bescherelle.ca/sans-que/

Comment: OK, merci pour cette précision

Comment: Your answer is saying something the OP obviously already knew. And the sentence given by OP already used the subjunctive, no hesitation about that, French natives would analyse it as being no other tense than the subjunctive. But, as pointed out in Gilles'SOnousesthostile's comment there is a spelling error, and this is a very frequent spelling error.